# Confidence of Google Vision OCR - TEXT_DETECTION mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-cloud-vision, google-vision

I've found out that using the TEXT_DETECTION mode provides better OCR results than the DOCUMENT_TEXT_DETECTION mode. Is there a way to receive the confidence level also on the TEXT_DETECTION mode and gain good readability results together with a confidence level?

https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/ocr#optical_character_recognition_ocr

Comment: The output for both types should be similar. You should get a confidence score for each character. I have tested to be sure. See the full output example at the end of the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/vision/docs/pdf)